# How to use Sqlquery for rodbc to query table with datetime filter

Tags: sql, r, oracle, datetime, rodbc

I am trying to query a table in an oracle db using R, the connection for rodbc works as i can pull out the top 10 records of the original table.

e.g. table in oracle database:

```
d1  DATE_ADDED
1   2014-11-03 13:04:54
2   2017-09-01 00:03:20
3   2018-03-02 09:40:36
4   2019-05-03 10:01:20
```

I start getting errors as soon as i add a where clause for a datetime field inside sqlquery:

```
SqlQuery(db,"select * from table where DATE_ADDED >= '2018-02-01T00:00:00'")
```

> ERROR: HY000 1843 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
sqlQuery(db,query <- paste(
  'SELECT *',
  'FROM table',
  paste0("WHERE DATE_ADDED BETWEEN " ,
         as.numeric(as.POSIXct('2018-02-01 00:00:00'))+3653*24*60*60," AND ",
as.numeric(as.POSIXct('2019-02-01 00:00:00'))+3653*24*60*60),sep='\n'))
```

> ERROR: HY000 932 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER

The DATE_ADDED field values in the original oracle db is datetime which looks like this: `2018-02-01 00:00:00`

Tried a few other methods (converting where clause datetime to numeric seconds however it returns an expected datatype error).

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? Try simply doing `SqlQuery(db,"select * from table where DATE_ADDED >= '2018-02-01'")`

Comment: In order to get a higher number of responses, I would recommend you to add more details to the problem you have, so people can reproduce the problem you are having, please take a look at the following guideline: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here are the errors: "HY000 1843 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month\n" and "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect ...